# Getting revisions data from Github gist

Tags: python, github, gist, github3.py

```
    gist_ids = 'abc'

    def main():
        gh = github3.login (
            token=os.environ.get('my_token'),
            url='  ')
        my_gist = gh.gist(gist_ids)

        resp = github3.gists.history.GistHistory( json, session=None)

        print json.dumps(resp)
   if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i am trying get the revision data form gist and store in the form of json.

New to python apis please light me folks

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "push.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "push.py", line 26, in main
    resp = github3.gists.history.GistHistory( json, session=None)
NameError: global name 'json' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to `import json` at the top of your file.

Comment: @Amber  imported json 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "push.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "push.py", line 27, in main
    resp = github3.gists.history.GistHistory( json, session=None)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/github3/models.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.etag = json.pop('ETag', None)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pop'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which version of github3.py you have installed you have two options:

1. If you're using an alpha version of 1.0 you should use the `commits()` method on your `my_gist` object. (Documentation: http://github3.readthedocs.io/en/develop/gists.html)
2. if you're using a 0.9 series version you should use the `iter_commits()` method on the same object. (Documentation: http://github3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gists.html#github3.gists.gist.Gist.iter_commits)

These will work roughly like this:

```
# 1.0.0a4
for gist_commit in my_gist.commits():
    # do stuff with previous version
# 0.9.6
for gist_commit in my_gist.iter_commits():
    # ...
```

Alternatively

```
# 1.0.0a4
my_gist_history = list(my_gist.commits())
# 0.9.6
my_gist_history = list(my_gist.iter_commits())
```